# how call Rest web service in loop in app Background?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an application with SWIFT, which sends the location of cars through a REST call. When the application goes to background after 7 minutes, the loop that is sending the location stops being sent.

Does anyone know of any way to keep the loop running?

In the documentation it informs that this is a normal behavior .. but it needs to continue making this call of REST.

Comment: Give us technical details like your API calling code and how you managed background execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to enable "iOS background data transfer". Check here an article on this topic: https://topologyeyewear.github.io/engineering-blog/2017/11/20/background_transfer/
Good luck!